# Search for specific text in XML tree and extract text in next node

Tags: xml, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, contains

Trying to scrape the weight of smartwatches from [www.currys.co.uk](http://www.currys.co.uk). The website does not follow the same structure for all products so to get the weight of each product I am trying to use a keyword search using `xpath`:

```
//text()[contains(.,'Weight')]
```

I can get the text "Weight", but what i want to get is the following `node` that `contains` the actual value of the weight:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <th scope = "row">Weight</th>
   <td> 26.7 g</td>
 <tr>
<body>
```

What I am looking for is to get the text `26.7 g`. I tried using the below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
//text()[contains(.,'Weight')]//td
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling::td`:

```
from lxml import etree


txt = '''<tbody>
 <tr>
   <th scope = "row">Weight</th>
   <td> 26.7 g</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>'''

root = etree.fromstring(txt)

for td in root.xpath('//th[contains(., "Weight")]/following-sibling::td'):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
 26.7 g
```

Comment: works brilliantly. Thank you. And just for future reference, in order to get the previous sibling, i just change the code above to be " /preceding-sibling::td " ?

Comment: @sophods Unfortunately, XPATH doesn't support functions for searching previous elements. Here is CSS/Xpath cheatsheet: https://devhints.io/xpath But there's `.getparent()` function in `lxml` - from there you can search all siblings.